# Question about eigenvector, basis for the solution

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I'm confused with some question currently I'm trying to solve. If you help that will be grateful.

Given the matrix find eigenvalues and eigenvectors
$$ A =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        4 & -2 & 1 \\
        2 & 0 & 1 \\
        2 & -2 & 3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$|A - \lambda I| = 0$$
$$|A - \lambda I| = (\lambda-2)^2(\lambda-3) $$
$$ \lambda_1 = 2, \lambda_2 = 3$$

Now in Case 1: $ \lambda = 2$ book states that:

> - $\begin{bmatrix}
>           2 & -2 & 1 \\
>           2 & -2 & 1 \\
>           2 & -2 & 1 \\
>           \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
>           x \\
>           y \\
>           z \\
>           \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
>           0 \\
>           0 \\
>           0 \\
>           \end{bmatrix} 
>   $ ,
>
> which reduces the single equation $2x-2y+z=0$. This equation obviously has a 2-dimensional solution space. With $y = 1$ and $z = 0$, we get $x = 1$ and, hence, obtain the basis eigenvector $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
>         1 \\
>         1 \\
>         0 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}$ . With $y = 0$ and $z=2$ we get $x = -1$ and hence the basis eigenvector  $v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
>         -1 \\
>         0 \\
>         2 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}$ . The 2-dimensional eigenspace of $\mathbf A$ associated with the repeated eigenvalue $\lambda = 2$ has basis $\{v1, v2\}$

Isn't $v = \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        -1 \\
        -2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$   is also an eigenvector? Cause it also fits to equation $2x-2y+z=0$

Comment: That's true. But $v=-v_1-v_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your third vector is a linear combination of the two vectors given in the solution, and hence does not produce anything new in the eigenspace.  A two-dimensional eigenspace has many possible bases.  (Your $v$ is equal to $-v_1-v_2$.)